# If priority queue is the implementation of min-heap, how does priority queue produces same result all the time

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

The min-heap of 2,1,3 is either 1,2,3 or 1,3,2.
Which means priority queue should result any of them...

Comment: for input `2 1 3`, priority queue will be `1 2 3`. just try on pen-paper by taking input one by one. you can check out source code here if wanted http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/util/PriorityQueue-source.html

Comment: (ex falso…: a *priority queue* can be implemented by a *min-heap* (or *max-heap*, if the *priority queue* is to hand out items in order of decreasing priority…)) Both min-heaps you show are valid. No *implementation of min-heap* is required to alternate between valid representations of the same collection of values.

Comment: If the elements can be inserted in any order, then why did you use the same order every time?